# Is it possible to load a swf file after application creation in flex?

Tags: apache-flex, load, flash

Is it possible to load a swf file after application creation in flex? If so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [SWFLoader](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/SWFLoader.html) class to load SWFs at runtime. You can either declare the required SWF using an MXML tag or use the [load(url)](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/SWFLoader.html#load%28%29) method.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the module loader, incase you have a tightly coupled code , but built into different logical parts.